# What is the difference in using cp and dd when cloning USB sticks?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, dd, cp

I found that there are at least two methods to clone a USB stick:
(with `/dev/sdb` as the source while `/dev/sdc` the target)

1. Cloning with `cp`:

   ```
   sudo cp /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
   ```
2. Cloning with `dd`:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4096
   ```

Are there any significant differences between the two commands and why is dd preferred over cp?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, the difference is that `dd` is constrained to reading 4096-byte blocks at a time, since you have used `bs=4096`. The likely effect is that `dd` will be much, much slower than `cp`. Try with a larger block size (`10M`, `50M`?).

The particular buffer size that's best suited for the current devices might be different from `cp`'s (or `cat`'s). You can't easily control `cp`'s buffering. `dd`'s utility shines when:

- you have *very* large devices to copy, so that experimenting to determine the best block-size is worthwhile.
- you have to copy only part of a disk. You can specify `count` to limit how many blocks are copied.
- you want to resume an interrupted copy. You can't do so with `cp`, but you can try with `dd`, by using the `seek` and `skip` options.
- you want to pipe it to the standard input of something (admittedly, `cat` will work here too):

  ```
  dd if=/dev/sda bs=10M | ssh host dd of=/dev/sdb
  ```

`dd` usefulness is very well discussed in this Unix and Linux post:
[dd vs cat — is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/70524)